# Swipe Down Gesture with Navigation Item

Tags: ios, objective-c, menu, navigation, swipe

Hi I am wanting to use a swipe down gesture to navigate back to the main menu. The problem is that I am using a navigation item (stemming from a Navigation Controller) and therefor the swipe down does not get detected. How may I solve this?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *bezelSwipeGestureRecognizer = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeBack:)];
    bezelSwipeGestureRecognizer.edges = UIRectEdgeTop;
    bezelSwipeGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:bezelSwipeGestureRecognizer];

    UIView *invisibleScrollPreventer = [UIView new];
    invisibleScrollPreventer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 100);
    [self.view addSubview:invisibleScrollPreventer];

}

-(void)swipeBack:(UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"Top Swipe");

        [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
-(void)swipeBack:(UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        NSLog(@"Top Swipe");

        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];


    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry I didn't make my question very clear. Basically the problem that I am having is the the swipe I am currently using is not even getting registered! The code that I am using works perfectly fine on ViewControllers just not UITableViews with navigationsItems.

Answer (score 0):

First, create an outlet to your gesture recognizer:

```
@IBOutlet var swipeDownGestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer!
```

Second, add the recognizer to your navigation bar:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDownGestureRecognizer)
```